# App runs on arm emulator but does not run on haxm emulator, unsatisfied link error?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Exception is here

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar"
```

Comment: https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried it does not work , still same

Comment: looks like you are using google maps, which requires google play services. Are you sure that both emulators have them?

Comment: @VladMatvienko my app uses an arm version of the maps library, where as I am trying to run this on an haxm emulator.  I need to understand how can I   provide the haxm library to the same .